# Model created in C++ can not be modified from QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

SOLVED: I did everything like eyllanesc answer and in my FirstPage.qml inside 
delegate where i access model data i put modelData before names. 
Previously  inside FirstPage.qml delegate i used: name, completed and 
uncompleted and now i use modelData.name, modelData.completed and 
modelData.uncompleted. It is all fine now.

I'm completely new in the QT/QML and I tried  but  could not find an answer for  my problem.

I use model (created in c++) in QML. When app starts everything is fine but when i try to add new element to model it is not displayed in QML. Model is the same like from the start.

I have class modcontroller and inside it i create list.

modcontroller.h

```
#ifndef MODCONTROLLER_H
#define MODCONTROLLER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <list.h>

class modcontroller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit modcontroller(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QList<QObject*> getList();

    Q_INVOKABLE void addList(QString nam);

signals:
    void listChanged();

public slots:

private:
    QList<QObject*> m_dataList;
};

#endif // MODCONTROLLER_H
```

modcontroller.cpp

```
#include "modcontroller.h"
#include <QDebug>

modcontroller::modcontroller(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    m_dataList.append(new List("Test"));
}

QList<QObject *> modcontroller::getList()
{
    return m_dataList;
}

void modcontroller::addList(QString nam)
{
    m_dataList.append(new List(nam));
    qDebug() << "Function addList called";

    qDebug() << m_dataList;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include "list.h"
#include "modcontroller.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);


    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;


    modcontroller controller;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myModel", QVariant::fromValue(controller.getList()));
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("controller",&controller);

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;



    return app.exec();
}
```

In QML file  i have ListView with `model: myModel`, and button with

```
onClicked: {
                controller.addList(textInput.text)
                myStackView.push(firstPage)
            }
```

When i click create i see only the first item "Test" that is created in the start but in the console i get this:

```
Function addList called
(List(0x2b7e60bc2c0), List(0x2b82d5891b0))
```

Thanks in advance.

main.qml

```
    ApplicationWindow {
        visible: true
        width: 580
        height: 360
        title: qsTr("Hello World")

        StackView{
            id: myStackView
            initialItem: firstPage
            anchors.fill: parent
        }

        Component{
            id: firstPage
            FirstPage{}
        }

        Component{
            id: createNewListPage
            CreateNewListPage{}
        }

    }
```

FirstPage.qml

```
Item {    
    ListView{
                id: lists
                width: 150
                height: childrenRect.height
                x: 15
                y: 70

                model: myModel

                delegate: Row{
                    width: 150
                    height: 25
                    spacing: 5

                    Rectangle{
                        width: {
                            if(uncompleted < 3){return 3;}
                            else if(uncompleted < 6){return 6;}
                            else {return 10;}
                        }
                        height: {
                            if(uncompleted < 3){return 3;}
                            else if(uncompleted < 6){return 6;}
                            else {return 10;}
                        }
                        radius: 10
                        color: "#494949"
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    }
                    Button {
                        id:button1
                        height: 23

                        contentItem: Text {
                            id: textTask
                            text: name
                            font.underline: true
                            color: "blue"
                            font.bold: true
                            font.pointSize: 10
                            height: 20
                            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                            anchors.left: parent.left
                        }

                        background: Rectangle {
                            id: rectangle
                            color: "transparent"
                        }
                        states:[
                            State {
                                name: "Hovering"
                                PropertyChanges {
                                    target: textTask
                                    color: "white"
                                    font.bold: true
                                    font.underline: false
                                }
                                PropertyChanges {
                                    target: rectangle
                                    color: "blue"
                                }
                            }]

                        MouseArea{
                            hoverEnabled: true
                            anchors.fill: button1
                            onEntered: { button1.state='Hovering'}
                            onExited: { button1.state=''}
                        }
                    }
                    Text{
                        font.pointSize: 8
                        text: {
                            if(uncompleted == 0)return "";
                            return "- " + uncompleted + " left";
                        }
                        color: "#494949"
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

CreateNewListPage.qml

```
Item {
   Rectangle{
       width: 580
       height: 360

       Rectangle{
        width: 350
        height: 30
        y: 100
        x: 30
        border.color: "#7b9cd3"
        border.width: 1

        TextInput {
            id: textInput
            anchors.topMargin: 3
            cursorVisible: true
            anchors.fill: parent
            font.bold: true
            font.pointSize: 14
        }

    }



       Button{
                height: 20
                text: "Create this list"
                onClicked: {
                    controller.addList(textInput.text)
                    myStackView.push(firstPage)
                }

                background: Rectangle{
                    id: rect1
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    radius: 20
                    border.color: "#88b6cf"
                    gradient: Gradient {
                            GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "#fcfefe" }
                            GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "#d5e8f3" }
                    }
                }

            }

     }
}
```

Comment: i added my qml files  and type List is class with QString and two integers. I use them in FirstPage.qml file like name, completed, uncompleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lists are a dummy model because by itself it does not notify the view if there is any change such as the number of elements, so a solution for your case is to make it a mod_controller's Q_PROPERTY, then when you add an item, the sign listChanged that will notify the view that something has changed and therefore needs to be repainted. It is not necessary to export the list separately from the controller since the Q_PROPERTY are accessible in QML, so the solution is:

**modcontroller.h**

```
#ifndef MODCONTROLLER_H
#define MODCONTROLLER_H

#include <QObject>

class modcontroller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<QObject *> lists READ getList NOTIFY listsChanged) // <---
public:
    explicit modcontroller(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    QList<QObject *> getList() const;
    Q_INVOKABLE void addList(const QString &nam);
    Q_SIGNAL void listsChanged();
private:
    QList<QObject*> m_dataList;
};

#endif // MODCONTROLLER_H
```

**modcontroller.cpp**

```
#include "modcontroller.h"
#include "list.h"

#include <QDebug>

modcontroller::modcontroller(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    m_dataList.append(new List("Test"));
}

QList<QObject *> modcontroller::getList() const
{
    return m_dataList;
}

void modcontroller::addList(const QString & nam)
{
    m_dataList.append(new List(nam));
    qDebug() << "Function addList called";
    qDebug() << m_dataList;
    Q_EMIT listsChanged(); // <---
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "modcontroller.h"

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    modcontroller controller;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("controller",&controller);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

In the case of QML, the binding is done with the Q_PROPERTY list of controller:

```
ListView{
    // ...
    model: controller.lists // <---
    // ...
```

Comment: @Peco do not share your files separately, upload it to github to easily help you

Comment: @Peco Checking the links I see that they are repeated files, that is, 2 different links point to the same file

Comment: @Peco I have made a PR to your repo.

Comment: now its working.. thank you very much.. I changed my FirstPage.qml and i put everywhere before name, completed and uncompleted modelData and it is working. Tanks again